Trial Balance in AX 2012
Can anyone let me know how the data is populated on the General Ledger->Common->Trial Balance Form Grid in AX 2012? As i am new to AX your knowledge sharing will b e useful for me.
I assume that it uses GeneralLedgerTrialDp class but couldn't able to find out the exact method that populates the data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There are essentially 2 processes that populate the data for the Trial Balance.
The first process updates dimension focus balances and the second process processes/calculates the trial balance based on the underlying dimension focus data using a trial balance report but displaying the data on the grid.
You can manually update the focus balances and follow the code to see how the underlying data gets created at:

\Menus\GeneralLedger\Setup\Financial dimensions\Financial dimension sets

The primary objects to look at are:

\Classes\DimensionFocusInitializeBalance
\Classes\DimensionFocusProcessBalance
\Classes\DimensionFocusUpdateBalance
\Data Dictionary\Tables\DimensionFocusBalance

Then the trial balance report that aggregates/calculates that underlying data is found at:

\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceDP

